# Same Center Ellipse Major and Minor Axes

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

[Ellipse Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yER7l.png)

I have two same center ellipses A, B, and C are known values X and Y arent known values and I need to obtain these values.

How can it be calculated?

Comment: They are not uniquely determined unless you impose some additional condition. For example if the outer ellipse was $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ you might want $a:b=A:B$

Comment: A/B=(A+Y)/(B+X) is also same because I need same ellipse with diffrent scale

Comment: what's the red line here?